# Unable to get data in foreach in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

here is my code in html, i am newbie in codeigniter i dont know what mistake i am making in my code. its a simple query to get records from table. please help me.

```
<?php foreach($records as $r):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$r['id']?></td>
                    <td><?=$r['name']?></td>
               </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

my controller code

```
   public function index(){
            /*$this->load->view('student/student_view');*/
            $data['records']=$this->student_model->getAll();
            $data['student']=0;
            $this->load->view('student/student_view',$data);
}
```

and my modal code

```
function getAll(){
        $query = $this->db->get('stud');    
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning an object like data from your modal, and you are fetching that data as array, so You need to change either modal as

```
function getAll(){
        $query = $this->db->get('stud');    
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

use same view no change in html code now.
Else
keep the same code for modal

```
function getAll(){
        $query = $this->db->get('stud');    
        return $query->result();
    }
```

change html view code

```
<?php foreach($records as $r):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$r->id?></td>
                    <td><?=$r->name?></td>
               </tr>

    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Usually we are using -> for objects and [] for fetching the array records. Hope this will work . Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

change your code

```
<?php foreach($records as $r):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$r['id']?></td>
                    <td><?=$r['name']?></td>
               </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

to

```
<?php foreach($records as $r){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $r['id']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['name']?></td>
               </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: `<?php echo 'x' ?>` and `<?= 'x' ?>` are the same.

Comment: could you print_r($r) inside foreach loop and tell me results